# C++ SegFault when dereferencing a pointer for cout

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, cout

I'm new to C++ and just trying to get a hang of it. It generally seems not too bad, but I stumbled upon this weird/pathological segfaulting behavior:

```
int main () {
  int* b;
  *b = 27;
  int c = *b;
  cout << "c points to " << c << endl; //OK                                                                                                                                      
  printf( "b points to %d\n", *b); //OK                                                                                                                                          
  // cout << "b points to " << (*b) << endl; - Not OK: segfaults!                                                                                                               
  return 0;
}
```

This program, as given, produces what you'd expect:

```
c points to 27
b points to 27
```

On the other hand, if you uncomment the second-to-last line, you get a program that crashes (seg-fault) in runtime. Why? This is a valid pointer.

Comment: Note, this question was merged with [Why does this program segfault upon printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256975/why-does-this-program-segfault-upon-printf?lq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int* b` points to an unknown memory address because it wasn't initialized.  If you initialized it to whatever null pointer value exists for your compiler (`0` until C++11, `nullptr` in C++11 and newer), you'd most certainly get a segfault earlier.  The problem lies in the fact that you allocated space for the pointer but not the data it points to.  If you instead did this:

```
int c = 27;
int* b = &c;

cout << "c points to " << c << endl;
printf ("b points to %d\n", *b);
cout << "b points to " << (*b) << endl;
```

Things would work because `int* b` refers to a memory location that is accessible by your program (since the memory is actually a part of your program).

If you leave a pointer uninitialized or assign a null value to it, you can't use it until it points to a memory address that you KNOW you can access.  For example, using dynamic allocation with the `new` operator will reserve memory for the data for you:

```
int* b = new int();
*b = 27;
int c = *b;

//output

delete b;
```

Answer (score 9):

**Update 3**

My answer to [Where exactly does C++ standard say dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614158/1708801) gives a much better answer to why using an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. The basic logic from  the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), section `24.2` *Iterator requirements*, specifically section `24.2.1` *In general* paragraph *5* and *10*  which respectively say (*emphasis mine*):

> [...][ Example: After the declaration of an **uninitialized pointer** x (as with int* x;), x **must always be assumed to have a singular value of a pointer**. —end example ] [...] **Dereferenceable values are always non-singular.**

**Update 2**

This was originally an answer to a *C* question with nearly identical circumstances but the original question I answered was merged with this one. I am updating my answer to include an answer specific to the new question and to the *C++* draft standard.

`b` has not be initialized and therefore it's value is *indeterminate* but you used indirection on `b` which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One possible simple fix would be to assign `b` to the address of an existing variable, for example:

```
int a ;
int* b = &a;
```

Another option would have been to use dynamic allocation via *new*.

For completeness sake we can see this is *undefined behavior* by going to the draft C++ standard section `5.3.1` *Unary operators* paragraph *1* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and **the result is an lvalue referring to the object** or function to which the expression points.[...]

and if we then go to section `3.10` *Lvalues and rvalues* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object. [...]

but `b` does not point to a valid *object*.

**Original Answer**

You did not allocate any memory to `f` nor `b` but you used indirection on both which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Update**

It is worth noting that cranking up the warning levels should have indicated this was a problem, for example using `gcc -Wall` gives me the following warning for this code:

```
warning: 'f' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

The simplest fix would be to assign `f` to point to a valid object like so:

```
char a ;
char *f = &a ;
```

Another options would be to use dynamic allocation, if you don't have a handy reference the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html) is not a bad place to start.

for completeness sake, if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) Annex `J.2` *Undefined behavior* paragraph *1* says:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

and includes the following bullet:

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).

The value of `f` and `b` are both automatic variables and are indeterminate since they are not initialized.

It is not clear from reading the referenced sections which statement makes it undefined but section `6.5.2.5` *Compound literals* paragraph *17* which is part of normative text has an example with the following text which uses the same language and says:

> [...]next time around p would have an indeterminate value, which would result in undefined behavior.

In the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) the paragraph is *16*.

Comment: To be pedantic, that last sentence isn't relevant, as the pointers haven't been assigned any value at all.  Their values are indeterminate.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Their values are indeterminate, let me strike that for now and rework it when I have the chance. I would consider that invalid but perhaps you are correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's nitpicking.  It's the word "assigned" that's the issue here.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, by this do you mean that they haven't been assigned a variable? But rather just directly given a value?

Comment: @Link I have updated the answer with a lot more details, but basically the pointers do not have a known value so by doing `*f` you would be accessing some indeterminate area of memory. Most likely memory your process does not have access to which in a unix like system will generate a seg fault.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you were indeed correct, the indeterminate value is *stored* not *assigned*.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer is valid in as much it's got a value. But the memory is probably not. It's your OS telling you that you are touching memory which isn't yours.

I'm frankly surprised it doesn't crash earlier than that.

---

Here's why:

```
int* b; // b is uninitialized.
*b = 27;
```

Where does `b` point? It might be somewhere valid, or somewhere totally off-limits. You can usually bet on the latter.

Here's a better way to do what you want.

```
int b1 = 27;
int *b = &b1;
```

Now `b` points to the location on the stack where `b1`s value is stored.

Comment: You're just telling him what a seg fault is, not really solving the problem.

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya - he just answered the OP answer. the solution is pretty clear.

Comment: Ok. So is the solution that I need to use new to make the int* hold a valid address?

Comment: Wait, so, why doesn't the second last line work? (sorry for being a thickhead)

Comment: There's probably a good reason, but it doesn't really matter. This is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @magus pwnsen: I added a solution, you could use `new` as well, but make sure you use `delete` when you are done with the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `f` is a pointer and it need to be allocated some memory for it.

Comment: Note the question was merged with a similar question. You probably want to update your answer to fit the new question.

Answer (score 1):

General rule: **initialize variable before using it**

`char* f;` is a variable. `*f` is usage of this variable. Like any variable, `f` must be initialized before usage.

Comment: Note the question was merged with a similar question. You probably want to update your answer to fit the new question.