# Assignment to un-initialised Integer Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, definition, ansi-c

How is the value 2 being stored since the pointer has not been initialised in the following code snippet ?

```
int *p;
*p = 2;
printf("%d %d\n",p,*p);
```

The Output for the above program is as follows :

```
0 2
```

I was reading "Expert C Programming" by Peter Linden, and found this :

```
float *pip = 3.141; /* Wont compile */
```

But then how is the above program giving an output ? Is it because of using GCC ? or am I missing something ?

### EDIT

I understand why `float *pip = 3.141` is not valid, since an address location has to be an integer.
So does this mean that p stores the memory address '0' and the value of '2' is being assigned to this address? Why is there no segmentation fault in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float *pip = 3.141;
```

`pip` is a pointer, a pointer must be initialized with an address (not with a value)

e.g:

```
float f[] = {0.1f, 0.2f, 3.14f};
float *pip = &f[2];
printf("%f\n", *pip);
```

EDIT:

Another one:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* allocates space */
*p = 2; /* Now you can use it */
printf("%p %d\n", (void *)p, *p);
free(p);
```

Comment: so based on the output p contains the address '0' , and the value of '2' is being stored at this address ?

Comment: No, p does not contain the address 0, but some garbage, you have to assign space with malloc or to some valid address before his use

Comment: then how come the printf statement printing the value 0 for the address?

Comment: Because of undefined behaviour, can print anything (or crash), also note that you have to use `(void *)p` to print the address of a pointer

Comment: is there a way to print the garbage address that p contains before malloc is used ?

Comment: `int *p;` `printf("%p\n", (void *)p);` `p = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: Yes, because p doesn't point to a valid address, as i told you undefined behaviour, anything can happen

Comment: Got it :) btw, is there an explanation why this is undefined ? Since what p contains is an unsigned integer after all?

Comment: Because a pointer must contain an address like 0x51b9040 and not a value like 2

Comment: Take a look to C FAQ (Section pointers) and you will understand

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
float* pip = 3.141
```

can be rewritten

```
float* pip;
pip = 3.141;
```

See the difference? Compare it to:

```
int* p;
*p = 2;
```

In the former case, you're trying to assign 3.141 as a *memory address*, while in the latter case, you're (validly) assigning 2 as a *value* to the *dereferenced* memory address.

Comment: i understand why pip cannot be assigned 3.141 since that is not a valid address.
so does that mean p points to address '0' (is this garbage value?) and the value of '2' is being stored at this address ?

Comment: `*p = 2` is potentially disastrous surely. You were just lucky that the program responded in a sensible fashion.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But then something more shocking :
http://ideone.com/hHvX1m two variables having the same address 0 ? or is there a mistake in the way i am printing the address ?

Comment: @Kyuubi - You're mistaken that the address starts as 0. The behavior is undefined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/where-exactly-does-c-standard-say-dereferencing-an-uninitialized-pointer-is-un.