# std::function to member function of object and lifetime of object

Tags: c++, c++11

If i have an instance of `std::function` that is bound to a member function of an object instance and that object instance goes out of scope and is otherwise destroyed will my `std::function` object now be considered to be a bad pointer that will fail if called?

Example:

```
int main(int argc,const char* argv){
    type* instance = new type();
    std::function<foo(bar)> func = std::bind(type::func,instance);
    delete instance;
    func(0);//is this an invalid call
}
```

Is there something in the standard that specifies what should happen? My hunch is that it will throw and exception because the object no longer exists

EDIT:
Does the standard specify what should happen?

Is it undefined behavior?

EDIT 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class foo{
public:
    void bar(int i){
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    foo* bar = new foo();
    std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(&foo::bar, bar,std::placeholders::_1);
    delete bar;
    f(0);//calling the dead objects function? Shouldn't this throw an exception?

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code i receive an output value of 0;

Comment: You mean _is this undefined behavior or what_?

Comment: Yes, as you are using a pointer. If you bound the object itself, IIRC that is copied.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior, or what can I expect to happen... An exception, it will work... something else. I am asking this in a theoretical context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What will happen is undefined behavior.

The `bind()` call will return some object that contains a copy of `instance`, so that when you call `func(0)` will effectively call:

```
(instance->*(&type::func))(0);
```

Dereferencing an invalid pointer, as you would do there if `instance` were `delete`d, is undefined behavior. It will not throw an exception (although, it's undefined, so it could, who knows).

Note that you're missing a placeholder in your call:

```
std::function<foo(bar)> func = 
    std::bind(type::func, instance, std::placeholders::_1);
//                                  ^^^^^^^ here ^^^^^^^^^
```

Without that, you can't call `func(0)` even with a non-deleted instance.

Updating your example code to better illustrate what's going on:

```
struct foo{
    int f;
    ~foo() { f = 0; }

    void bar(int i) {
        std::cout << i+f << std::endl;
    }
};
```

With that added destructor, you can see the difference between copying the pointer (in `f`) and copying the object that was pointed to (in `g`):

```
foo* bar = new foo{42};
std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(&foo::bar, bar, std::placeholders::_1);
std::function<void(int)> g = std::bind(&foo::bar, *bar, std::placeholders::_1);
f(100); // prints 142
g(100); // prints 142
delete bar;
f(100); // prints 100
g(100); // prints 142 still, because it has a copy of
        // the object bar pointed to, rather than a copy
        // of the pointer
```

Comment: @ Barry The code was just an example, but yes thanks the placeholder is needed. Is there somewhere in the standard i can reference for that?

Comment: @AlexZywicki Check out [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/where-exactly-does-c-standard-say-dereferencing-an-uninitialized-pointer-is-un)

Comment: At least in the case of a POD pointer type the behavior would be undefined. Does the `std::function` type resolve to a pointer internally?

Comment: @AlexZywicki You can think of `std::function<R(Args...)>` as having some internal private type `placeholder` with `virtual R call(Args...) = 0;` that will be implemented by some specific `holder<T>` which holds the `T` you construct it with. Regardless of how your library implements it, it's a reasonable mental model for how `std::function` works.

Comment: So does it copy the instance of the object you bind it to or does it hold a pointer/reference to that object. I just tried it out and it does not break in any way if the object no longer exists... Which leads me to believe that it is making a copy.

Comment: @AlexZywicki It copies the *pointer* - not the object. If you want to copy the object you have to call `bind(&some_method, *instance)`. That will avoid the dangling pointer. You can verify yourself with a simple example by making the destructor of your type zero out (or otherwise change) member values.

Comment: @AlexZywicki Updated my answer - hope that clarifies things.

Comment: What I'm confused about is how the last two function call are even valid because the object `bar` to which the `std::function` objects were bound to no longer exists thus making it an invalid pointer to the objects `bar`, which in my mind should throw just as if i used a regular pointer that was dead.

Comment: @AlexZywicki It shouldn't throw. It's just undefined behavior that happens to do something valid-ish. This code, using my `foo`, prints 5: `foo* bar2 = new foo{100}; delete bar2; bar2->bar(5);`.

Comment: It seems to be ignoring the instance variable or using them as uninitialized data.

Comment: @AlexZywicki I believe that it calls what is supposed to be a method `bar` of the object which supposed to be pointed by pointer `bar`. The reason why it executes normally even after `delete bar` is that this memory hasn't been corrupted/overwritten (yet) and the object as well as all it's ivars still stay "there". Problems will occur when you have a lot of other things going on in your code.

Comment: @peetonn so essentially i have a dangling pointer to a piece of memory that i no longer own but still has semi-valid data for now?

Comment: @AlexZywicki no, you shouldn't rely on this memory at all as it's not guaranteed what's in there. it could be valid, could be not. consider the worst.

Comment: @peetonn I didn't plan on relying on it, i was just restating what you said in a way that I understood.