# Calling std::function object pointing to the method of deallocated object

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders; 

typedef function<void(const int&)> SomeFunc;

class X {
public:
    X(string name):name_(name)
    { cout << "ctor " << name_ << endl; }

    ~X()
    {
        cout << "dtor " << name_ << endl; 
        name_ = "empty";
    }

    SomeFunc
    getSomeFunc()
    { return bind(&X::someMethod, this, _1); }

private:
    string name_;

    void
    someMethod(const int& a)
    {
        cout << name_ << " some method with " << a << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    SomeFunc f;

    {
        shared_ptr<X> x(new X("Object"));
        f = x->getSomeFunc();
        f(1);
    }

    f(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes, output gives me this:

```
ctor Object
Object some method with 1
dtor Object
empty some method with 2
```

other times this:

```
ctor Object
Object some method with 1
dtor Object
 some method with 2
```

In real world, it would most probably give me crashes once deallocated object tries to access it's attributes. 
So here is a question - as function does not guarantee holding a reference to the object which method it's pointing to, what is the best practice to avoid crashes when function is called after referenced object was already deallocated?

One of the solutions I might think of - maintain a special flag `bool deallocated_` inside object and check it inside the method which might be called after deallocation. However, I suspect, it's not reliable either.

**UPDATE (from comments):**

The real reason I need this workaround is the library that takes function as a parameter. This library operates asynchronously and I have no control over function objects passed into it. That's why when my object is deallocated, library still can invoke callbacks using originally passed function which leads to a crash.

Comment: The cute answer is "well don't do that silly".

Comment: Um, if you use dangling pointers, you get what you get. What is your real question? If you're asking how to manage ownership better, the answer is to manage ownership better.

Comment: I asked this the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054303/stdfunction-to-member-function-of-object-and-lifetime-of-object maybe it can help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit @MorphingDragon the real reason is the library that takes function as a parameter. This library operates asynchronously and I have no control over function objects passed into it. That's why when my object is deallocated, library still can invoke callbacks using originally passed function which leads to a crash. I wish the library had something like `unregsiterCallbacks` call...

Comment: @peetonn: Yeah pretty poor library if it doesn't. Do callbacks "stack", or does a newly-registered callback replace a previously-registered one? And is it safe to "register" a singular function pointer (one that doesn't point anywhere, like a "null pointer")? If so, there's your answer: `registerCallback(nullptr);` Though you also say you have "no control" over what's passed into the library. Why do you have a design that gives you so little control over anything? And who _does_ have control? I maintain that this is a design issue and patching around it is not optimal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it stacks callbacks, so registering a nullptr won't help, although a good idea in the first case. All what library call takes as an argument is a 'SomeFunc' object. It's a third-party lib, but I'll talk with the developer about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sulution 1)** Using weak_ptr + lambda (almost the same as from **b4hand**, but it won't force your class beeing alive)

Inherit your class from std::enable_shared_from_this

```
class X : public enable_shared_from_this<X>
```

and change getSomeFunc to something like this:

```
SomeFunc getSomeFunc()
{
    weak_ptr<X> weak = shared_from_this();

    return [weak, this](const int& a){
        shared_ptr<X> shared = weak.lock();

        if (shared)
        {
            this->someMethod(a);
        }
    };
}
```

output:

```
ctor Object
Object some method with 1
dtor Object
```

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231627/1864364) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428083/1864364).

**Solution 2)** A bit of crazy code + lambda
If you can't or don't want to use shared/weak ptrs, you can do it this way:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

typedef function<void(const int&)> SomeFunc;

class X {
private:
    static set<X*> _aliveInstanties;
public:
    X(string name) :name_(name)
    {
        _aliveInstanties.insert(this);

        cout << "ctor " << name_ << endl;
    }

    ~X()
    {
        _aliveInstanties.erase(_aliveInstanties.find(this));

        cout << "dtor " << name_ << endl;
        name_ = "empty";
    }

    SomeFunc getSomeFunc()
    {
        return [this](const int& a)
        {
            if (_aliveInstanties.find(this) != _aliveInstanties.end())
            {
                this->someMethod(a);
            }
        };
    }

private:
    string name_;

    void someMethod(const int& a)
    {
        cout << name_ << " some method with " << a << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, @VinSmile. your solution #1 works perfectly for me - no need to hold an object for a function to be called.

Answer (score 3):

Your object is being held by a `shared_ptr`, so you can use a lambda to close over the `shared_ptr`:

```
auto func = [ptr](const int &p){ ptr->someMethod(p); };
```

You'll need to use `shared_from_this` to get `ptr` within the class.

Here's a full example that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders; 

typedef function<void(const int&)> SomeFunc;

class X : public enable_shared_from_this<X> {
public:
    X(string name) : name_(name) {
        cout << "ctor " << name_ << endl;
    }

    ~X() {
        cout << "dtor " << name_ << endl; 
        name_ = "empty";
    }

    SomeFunc getSomeFunc() {
        auto ptr = shared_from_this();
        return [ptr](const int &a){ ptr->someMethod(a); };
    }

private:
    string name_;

    void someMethod(const int& a) {
        cout << name_ << " some method with " << a << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    SomeFunc f;

    {
        shared_ptr<X> x(new X("Object"));
        f = x->getSomeFunc();
        f(1);
    }

    f(2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
ctor Object
Object some method with 1
Object some method with 2
dtor Object
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Closures are typically the tool to make sure particular state lives long enough.

Comment: Downvote removed - in your last edit, you fixed your "dangling reference" bug.  I'm sure you noticed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that holds a function pointer and a `shared_ptr` to the object. The `shared_ptr` to the object guarantees the object won't be destroyed until your function class is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using lambda is to derive from `enable_shared_from_this` and pass `shared_from_this` in `getSomeFunc` method:

```
class X : public enable_shared_from_this<X> {
public:
    X(string name):name_(name)
    { cout << "ctor " << name_ << endl; }

    ~X()
    {
        cout << "dtor " << name_ << endl; 
        name_ = "empty";
    }

    SomeFunc
    getSomeFunc()
    { 
        return bind(&X::someMethod, shared_from_this(), _1); 
    }

private:
    string name_;

    void
    someMethod(const int& a)
    {
        cout << name_ << " some method with " << a << endl;
    }   
};
```

This, however, will hold object until all callbacks are released.