# why does this if statement not seg fault [C++]

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

let's say I define a pointer variable to be of some class type ptrClass:

```
ptrClass *ptr;
```

and let's say this `ptrClass` has a member function called `get()` that returns a pointer that is pointing to nothing.

so if we do:

```
ptr->get();
```

this would result in a seg fault.

but if we do `if(ptr->get())`, this does not result in a seg fault (the if statement simply does not execute). Can someone explain why this is the case? In order to check the if statement condition, doesn't the program perform `ptr->get()`, which should result in seg fault?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example code that reproduces the error? We don't know anything about ptrClass

Comment: You simply have **undefined behavior** dereferencing an uninitialized `ptrClass *ptr;` pointer, which your sample proves well.

Comment: Using `ptr->get()` is undefined behavior when `ptr` does not point to a valid object. It's pointless trying to make sense of undefined behavior. By definition, it is undefined. Anything can happen.

Comment: And insightful http://stackoverflow.com/a/4286034/4743711

Answer (score 1):

Code with bugs in it will do things you don't expect. It really is that simple. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Calling method of invalid pointer is undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

You don't show what `get()` does but if `get()` does not use `this` and is not `virtual`, the programme will not dereference `ptr` so it won't use an invalid pointer.