# Is it possible to create a struct inside the same uncreated struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, struct

Is the following declaration possible? If so, how do you access the elements inside the struct? It compiles but I cannot access the elements.

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *node1;
int main()
{
    node1->a = 5; // I cannot perform this operation
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a typical structure layout for a pretty common and standard single-linked list. You access the members like you do any other structure.

Comment: The `node *` is probably better understood as creating a pointer inside a `struct`.

Comment: what do you mean with "i cannot access the elements" ? There is no attempt of accessing elements in the code you show here. Please show what you tried and the error messages you get. See also: [mcve]

Comment: By the way in C++ you don't need to write `struct node *` just `node*` is fine (it's different from C in that regard). Though ideally you'd use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer

Comment: In fact in C++ you should be using [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and leave this _struct wiring_ to academia and bad C++ interviewers.

Comment: It was from an interview indeed

Comment: @Ron I dont agree in this generality. I write simple containers on a daily basis for stuff that I could as well put inside a `std::pair`.

Comment: @user463035818 What's wrong with `std::pair` ? o.O

Comment: @user463035818 `std::pair` is not a container.

Comment: @George `first` and `second` are rarely meaningful names. `std::pair` is good for generic code where you have no better names, but if I can name my members then I do it

Comment: @user463035818 You can always combine containers and smart pointers to produce the storage class of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to review the basics of the language. So maybe a link to the booklist is in order:

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1025391)

---

To address your questions:

Here you define a type, i.e., a *struct named node*, as containing an object of type `int` and an object of type *pointer to an object of type node* (`struct node*`):

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Here you declare a global object of type *pointer to an object of type node*:

```
struct node *node1;
```

Note that pointers are invalid by default, that is, they don't point to an object automatically.

So you have a pointer, but you don't actually have an *object of type node*.
Therefore you are not allowed to dereference the pointer. It is forbidden to access the (arbitrary) memory location the pointer currently happens to point at.

```
int main()
{
    node1->a = 5; // It is forbidden to perform this operation
    return 0;
}
```

In order to fix this. You need to create an object and let the pointer point to it.

Example:

```
int main() {
    node n; // create an object of type node
    node1 = &n; // Assign the address of the object n to the pointer
    node1->a = 5; // Now it's allowed to dereference the pointer
}
```

And finally:

> Is it possible to create a struct inside the same uncreated struct?

You can have a type that contains pointers to objects of the same type. This can be useful to implement recursive data structures, e.g., linked lists or trees.

For further reading:

- [C++ Different types of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47070065/1025391)
- [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/1025391)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your MCVE, you don't create the node, you have an uninitialised pointer. The `node* next` seems to be a red herring to your current problem.

```
struct node
{
    int a;
    node *next; // seems to be a red herring to your current problem.
};

int main()
{
    node node1; // <-- for this demo, create it on the stack
    node1.a = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Note; the `node *` is probably better understood as creating a pointer to a structure of the same type inside a `struct` (which is allowed), not so much a "struct in an uncreated struct".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access fields because you created just a pointer, to a struct instance, but not the last one. Accessing elements thw way like this is an undefined behavior. To make it correct, you should write for example

```
struct node *node1;
int main()
{
    node1 = new node();
    node1->a = 5; // now ok
    node1->next = new node(); // again, before this we had an unitialized ptr.
    return 0;
}
```

The other question that it isn't a very efficient way in this context.