# values of uninitialized pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

suppose we have the following declarations in C :

```
double d[25], * p;
int * t;
char * c;
```

How can we explaine the following printf() results ?

```
printf("d : %x\t",d);
printf("p : %x\t",p);
printf("t : %x\t",t);
printf("c : %x\t",c);
```

which print the ligne :

```
d : 62fd30    p : 1    t : 0    c : 39
```

We can clairly see the memory adress of d but both p, t and c don't look like adresses. I used to think that a uninitialized pointer takes the Null value after its declaration. Am I wrong? how can we explain these results?

Comment: It cannot be explained, it's undefined behaviour. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. You can explain it by looking at the generated assembly which will by no means be consistent with the code.

Comment: Aside: a pointer should be printed like this: `printf("p : %p\t", (void*)p);`. Using `%x` may happen to give the right value but not if `int` is 32 bits and a pointer is 64 bits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because undefined behaviour cannot be explained.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is not "aside", it is *essential*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "aside" because that was not the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane Having *2* different UBs doesn't cancel each other...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that is why I wrote an "aside" which mentioned the right way to do it..

Comment: The question was "how can we explain these results"... :D

Answer (score 5):

*All* automatic (non-static local) variables will by default be uninitialized with an *indeterminate* value (that can seem like random or garbage). It doesn't matter if the variable is a pointer or not.

Also, just reading the value of an uninitialized pointer isn't automatically UB (in C), but *dereferencing* an uninitialized pointer definitely is.

However, as mentioned in one comment, you need to use `"%p"` to print pointers (technically they need to be casted to `void *` as well). Mismatching `printf` format specifier and argument type *do* lead to UB.

Comment: Hm, in practice you are right, but in theory, reading the pointer could be UB (remember that trap-representation-thingie?)

Comment: Use of an indeterminate value in a library function is UB too.

Comment: @Ctx True, but I doubt few of us will ever work on a system where pointers are not simple integers and can have trap values. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *few of us will ever work on a system where pointers are not simple integers*  To be pedantic, there are probably [very, very few of us alive who **haven't**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode)  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh I completely repressed memories of that. Please excuse me while I go curl up crying in the shower... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assume any pointer will be zero-initialized after declaration - C standard does not imply anything at that point. Same goes  with other types of values. This is why it is a good practice to set a value of a variable upon declaration, like:

`int * t = NULL;`

Some compilers do zero-initialize variables, but this is tool-specific feature.

Comment: I would say, it is only good practice to initialize it, if there is a chance that this initialization value is indeed used somewhere. Otherwise, it is ugly code.

Answer (score 3):

> I used to think that a **uninitialized pointer** takes the **Null**
>   value after its declaration. Am I wrong?

**Yes**, your assumption are incorrect. An **uninitialized pointer** declared with **automatic storage** always contains garbage or junk data i.e not a valid address, hence its better to initialize with `NULL` at first while declaring. For e.g

```
double *d = NULL;
/* some processing */
if(d == NULL) {
  /* @TODO error handling. Not allowed to de-reference NULL pointer */
}
```

Here

```
double d[25];
printf("d : %x\t",d);
```

`d` is an array of `25` double's & **array name itself address**, while printing `d` using `%x` causes **undefined behavior**, even your compiler could have warned you like this

> main.c:5:19: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int'but the
>   argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]

But you seems to ignore compiler warnings, one shouldn't. Always compiler your code with minimal flags like `-Wall`. For e.g

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic test.c
```

To print array name, use `%p` format specifier. for e.g

```
double d[25];
printf("Array d : %p\t",(void*)d);
```

Similarly with `int` pointer `t` and `char` pointer `c`, use `%p` format specifier instead of `%x`. Also don't keep any uninitialized pointer in your code.

```
int * t; /* initialized with valid address else 
            dereferencing uninitialized pointer causes UB */
printf("t : %p\n",(void*)t);
```