# constructor's problem to initialize pointer data member

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I encountered a  problem while initializing a pointer data member i.e int* apex; inside a constructor
having parameter as    int i = 0; as *apex = i;
but unfortunately nothing is executed after compiler strikes this line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
    int *apex;      
public:
    explicit base(int i = 0){
        cout << "this does executes" << endl;
        *apex = i; // <<<<<--- problem???
        cout << "this doesnt executes" << endl;
    }
};

int main(void){
    base test_object(7);
    cout << "this also doesnt executes";
}


// I know how to avoid this but i want to know what
// exactly the problem is associated with *apex = i;
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**
*note-no error is generated*

Comment: You never intialize the pointer to point at valid memory. so `*apex` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: This has nothing to do with constructors or classes.  It has everything to do with dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where exactly does C++ standard say dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/where-exactly-does-c-standard-say-dereferencing-an-uninitialized-pointer-is-un)

Comment: You can only initialize member variables in the constructor's initializer list. What you're doing is assignment, and you're not assigning to the pointer but to some non-existent thing.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
int *apex;
*apex = 42;
```

which is undefined behavior (UB), which includes that the compiler might just include code to stop execution or to start playing the song Never Gonna Give You Up by Rick Astley.

Even

```
int *apex = nullptr;
*apex = 42;
```

would be UB because the `int*` pointer has to point to a valid `int` when dereferencing via `*`

Just write

```
class base{
    int apex{};      
public:
    explicit base(int i) : apex(i){}
};
```

And be done for

Comment: Yes, or `explicit base(int i = 0) : apex{ new int(i) } {}` if `apex` really needs to be a pointer for some reason.

Comment: Nope in general than this should be in a `std::unique_ptr<int>` and using `std::make_unique<int>(i)` then, otherwise it very much depends on the reason why this has to be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Trust me I am ashamed of myself after this silly doubt.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
    int *apex;      
public:
    explicit base(int i = 0){
        apex = new int;
        // this is what i was supposed to do
        *apex = i;
    }
};

int main(void){
    base test_object(7);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your pointer points  to invalid address you didn't initialize it
This will fix what you have asked to be done.

```
using namespace std;

class base{
    int *apex{nullptr};      
public:
    explicit base(int& i ): apex{&i} {
        cout << "this does executes" << endl;
        cout << "this doesnt executes" << endl;
    }
};

int main(void){
    int a = 7
    base test_object(a);
    cout << "this also doesnt executes";
}
```

Make sure something (`int`) given to ctor has longer lifetime than an instance.

Comment: no. This is wrong. UB is lurking around the corner, because `apex` stores a dangling pointer. `i` is local to the constructor

Comment: now it is different but still wrong. "Make sure something given to ctor has longer lifetime than an instance" you are not doing that in your example. The pointer is still invalid

Comment: well, no, actually this doesnt compile

Comment: now it isnt wrong, but my interpretation of the question is different. It rather looks like OP wants to take the value not the pointer when they write `*apex = i;`, I might be wrong of course

Comment: I only considered this part of question. "I encountered a problem while initializing a pointer data member"