# Weird bug in pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to access single bytes of an int value via the code below. My problem is that whenever I try to remove `long int i=0;` from the code, it gives me a segmentation fault. Is there any reason this happens? I am not using I anywhere in the code.

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    
    unsigned int* a; 
    
    unsigned char* b1;
    unsigned char* b2; 
    unsigned char* b3; 
    unsigned char* b4;
    
    *a= 4294967295; //set to max val (4 bytes)
    //*************************
    long int i=0;//Q. Why long int/long long int? 
    //*************************
    
    b1 = (unsigned char*)(a);
    b2 = b1+(long long int)1;
    b3 = b1+(long long int)2;
    b4 = b1+(long long int)3;
    
    std::cout <<*a<<" "<<(int)*b1<<" "<<(int)*b2<<" "<<(int)*b3<<" "<<(int)*b4<<std::endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointer `a` is never initialized to point anywhere. So when you dereference it you will have *undefined behavior*. Simple solution: Make `a` a value instead of a pointer, as in `unsigned int a = 4294967295;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exhibits undefined behavior:

```
unsigned int* a; 
*a= 4294967295; //set to max val (4 bytes)
```

The pointer variable `a` is never initialized to anything, so it points to a random memory address. Writing anything to that random garbage address (typically) causes a segmentation fault. It's just coincidence that adding another variable changes the behavior (due to a change in memory layout of the program).

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that `*b2` and others are UB as well. Pointer arithmetics is only defined for pointers into an array.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Even for `unsigned char*`? How can a user re-implement `memcpy`  then?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't quite understand. `unsigned char*` is (also) an array type.

Comment: @PMF oh sorry, I was wrong. Once `a` is fixed the `bx` are allowed to alias it because they are char pointers

Answer (score 0):

The posted program has Undefined Behavior<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
unsigned int* a;  // Uninitialized local variable, it has an indeterminated value. 
*a = 4294967295;  // Where is it assigned?
```

It's unfortunate that it happens to "work" in your environment, you should [enable more warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/bf7r3Ycr8).

Since C++20, you can use [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to reinterpret an object representation:

```
#include <array>
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  auto a{ 4294967295LL };
  using repr_t = std::array<std::byte, sizeof(a)>;
  
  auto b{ std::bit_cast<repr_t>(a) };
  
  // The following outputs:      4294967295   255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0
  std::cout << a << "  ";
  for (auto i : b)
    std::cout << ' ' << static_cast<int>(i);
  std::cout << '\n';    
}
```

---

(1) See e.g.:

[Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

[Where exactly does C++ standard say dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285895/where-exactly-does-c-standard-say-dereferencing-an-uninitialized-pointer-is-un)